# How can I have Prism/Unity automatically resolve a View (UserControl)?

Tags: dependency-injection, module, unity-container, prism, composite

In a Composite Application (Prism), **when my module loads**, I get this error:

> {"The current build operation (build
>   key Build
>   Key[CustomersModul.ViewModels.CustomerAllViewModel,
>   null]) failed: The parameter view
>   could not be resolved when attempting
>   to call constructor
>   CustomersModul.ViewModels.CustomerAllViewModel(CustomersModul.Views.CustomerAllView
>   view). (Strategy type
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy,
>   index 2)"}

I am **resolving** this class:

```
CustomerAllViewModel layoutManager = this.container.Resolve<CustomerAllViewModel>();
```

And that class looks like **this**:

```
public class CustomerAllViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CustomerAllView View { get; set; }
    public ICommand TextChangeCommand { get; set; }
    private Customer customer;

public CustomerAllViewModel(CustomerAllView view)
{
    View = view;
    view.DataContext = this;
    ...
```

Normally I resolve **Presenters** which have no constructor parameters and instantiate their views internally. This is the first time I am using a **ViewModel** which accepts a View as parameter.

Interestingly, when I go to the view with **Resharper**, it asks me if I want to go to the XAML or code behind, so perhaps Prism is getting confused which one to instantiate?

**How can I get Prism to automatically instantiate this view (UserControl with XAML and code-behind) in the parameter?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes this is actually not the error, but something else.  Look at the inner exceptions, or call Microsoft.Practices.Composite.ExceptionExtensions.GetRootException(ex) to get the root exception.  You'll likely find there is some error being thrown in one of your constructors you are not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the CustomerAllView to the container? I usually get this error when I have forgot to add a type to the container.